# Upgrading docker artifactory pro 6.X to 7.X

Tags: docker, docker-compose, upgrade, artifactory

compose artifactory pro v6.9.0 running

In my compose I have two services :

```
image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:6.9.0
image: docker.io/library/postgres:9.6.11
```

I was able to upgrade to 6.23.13 without any problem just by changing the version of the image.

When I try the same thing with  any 7.X version (after upgrading to at least 6.10 as the doc says), I have errors.

For example, trying 7.21.3, I have these warnings

```
2022-08-01T08:41:30.343L [tomct] [WARNING] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored 
2022-08-01T08:41:30.343L [tomct] [WARNING] [                ] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig] [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - A docBase [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory.war] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored 
...
2022-08-01T08:41:37.344Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [ce1b2553475da56b] [c.z.h.p.ProxyConnection:182   ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - HikariCP Main - Connection org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@1597179442 (XID = 24), (SESSIONID = 3), (DATABASE = {db.home}), (DRDAID = null)  marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(0A000), ErrorCode(20000)
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Feature not implemented: No details.
```

and these errors

```
08:41:34,803 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an Appender of type [org.artifactory.usage.appender.UsageTrafficTimeBasedRollingFileAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type org.artifactory.usage.appender.UsageTrafficTimeBasedRollingFileAppender
...
2022-08-01T08:41:37.113Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [ce1b2553475da56b] [d.d.l.DbDistributeLocksDao:506] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Unable to detect database version Unable to get connection from unique lock data source
2022-08-01T08:41:37.353Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [ce1b2553475da56b] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:55] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed initializing Home. Caught exception: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find database table: db_properties
```

After reading the [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory) I do not clearly understand if I have to download the new docker-compose package from jfrog. I've tried but once there, the config.sh ask for external database and no question about reusing existing `image` directory.

Thx for help

Comment: Can you confirm you tried upgrading from 6.23.13 to 7.21.3?

Comment: yes I have tried this,  6.23.13 -> 7.21.3,
The logs are from this attempt

Comment: As there was no docker-compose method available in 6.x version therefore there was no straightforward approach. You should follow this wiki link (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-dockercomposeupgrade) for upgrading

Comment: Ok, I've managed to migrate the database, but the directory structure for the filestorage has changed, I have also moved this filestorage folder in the good place.
Moving from 6 to 7 is not smooth

Comment: @bodtx, did you find any solution?

Comment: no as this migration needs too much effort and tests we will use as it is and look to migrate our repository to our gitlab

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant for you, but I got the same problem. As far as I see there are new DB connection environment variables, that must be set. This error message is just a symptom, because without the new DB connection env, Artifactory will try to use an in-memory database (Apache Derby). Something like this is needed to fix it (as Docker Compose config of the Artifactory container):

```
 environment:
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_TYPE=postgresql
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_USERNAME=${POSTGRESQL_USERNAME}
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD}
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresql:5432/artifactory
  - JF_SHARED_DATABASE_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
```